# resources to make java card application similiar like RB 5.0

Tags: java, resources, javacard, jcop

I am making java app which main function is to write data on java card 36k, so I need resources ,tutorials about java cards,stuff like that.? I have  no experience making java card apps, so please give me any helpful resources..

## I am making application like RB 5.0 , if u can give me src code of this app will be better :)

Comment: Questions that requesting programs or tutorials are of topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart card specifications:

1. [Global Platform Card Specification](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/GPCardSpec_v2.2.pdf) (This is v 2.2.0.7, your card may was compatible a lower version)
2. [ISO/IEC 7816](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7816) (Regularly you need part 3 and 4)

Java Card applet development kit (including API Specifications + RE and VM Specification):

- [Java Card Development Kit 3.0.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javacard/downloads/javacard-sdk-2043229.html) (Download the version that is compatible with your card)

Java application library to communicate with smart cards:

- [javax.smartcardio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/package-summary.html) (As far as I know it is removed from Java Development Kit in the newer version)

A sample Java card applet: (A HelloWorld, stolen from [here](https://umer555.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/java-card-hello-world-applet/)):

```
package helloWorldPackage;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.Util;

public class HelloWorldApplet extends Applet {
         private static final byte[] helloWorld = {(byte)'H',(byte)'e',(byte)'l',(byte)'l',(byte)'o',(byte)' ',(byte)'W',(byte)'o',(byte)'r',(byte)'l',(byte)'d',};

         private static final byte HW_CLA = (byte)0x80;
         private static final byte HW_INS = (byte)0x00;

         public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
             new HelloWorldApplet().register(bArray, (short) (bOffset + 1), bArray[bOffset]);
         }

         public void process(APDU apdu) {

             if (selectingApplet()) {
             return;
         }

         byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
         byte CLA = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] & 0xFF);
         byte INS = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] & 0xFF);

         if (CLA != HW_CLA)
        {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }

          switch ( INS ) {
             case HW_INS:
               getHelloWorld( apdu );
               break;
            default:
               ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
         }
   }

  private void getHelloWorld( APDU apdu)
  {
      byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
      short length = (short) helloWorld.length;

      Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(helloWorld, (short)0, buffer, (short)0, (short) length);

      apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0, length);
  }
}
```

Related Java program to work with above applet (Stolen from [here](http://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/pcsc-sample-in-java.html) and modified after that):

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.smartcardio.*;

public class Blog {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   // Display the list of terminals
   TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
   List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
   System.out.println("Terminals: " + terminals);

   // Use the first terminal
   CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);

   // Connect with the card
   Card card = terminal.connect("*");
   System.out.println("card: " + card);
   CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();

   // Send Select Applet command
   byte[] aid = {(byte)0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x62, 0x03, 0x01, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x01}; //Replace your Applet AID instead of this AID here.
   ResponseAPDU answer = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, aid));
   System.out.println("answer: " + answer.toString());

   // Send test command
   answer = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00));
   System.out.println("answer: " + answer.toString());
   byte r[] = answer.getData();
   for (int i=0; i<r.length; i++)
    System.out.print((char)r[i]);
   System.out.println();

   // Disconnect the card
   card.disconnect(false);
  } catch(Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Ouch: " + e.toString());
  }
 }
}
```

---

You must convert you applet from `.java` to `.class` and from `.class` to `.cap` file. the JCDK contained required tools for that. To make this process simpler you can use [Eclipse-JCDE](http://eclipse-jcde.sourceforge.net/) plugin in *Eclipse IDE* (for Java Card 2.2.2) or Netbeans IDE plugins for Java Card (That is included in newer versions by default.)

After generating the `.CAP` file you need to upload and install it on the card. to aim this goal you can use the great well-documented opensource tool named [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro).

After installation you can use the Java program that mentioned above to communicate with your applet, or instead you can use another opensource tool named [OpenSC-Tool](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki) to send APDU commands to card and receive responses.

Comment: +1 for this extensive answer to a horrible question. With a bit of luck you get reversal badge for it. But please just close that kind question down instead of answering, SO doesn't want to encourage horrible questions.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Oops, You are right, it encourage horrible questions. I was in doubt about leaving the question unanswered or leaving an answer.Now I know I must leave them unanswered.  Thank you. :)